# Regarding HazelCast mapstore load and loadAll methods

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a question regarding MapStore implementation of load and loadAll methods

I have loaded list of 10 keys using loadAllKeys() method

for each key I have 1000's of records which is list of values

Example: 'storeId': listOf(products)

So I am creating the list while calling the load(key)

```
public synchronized List<Pojo> load(String key) {
   return List<Pojo>;
}
public synchronized Map<String, Pojo> loadAll(Collection<String> keys) 
{
    List<Pojo> listPojo = null;
    HashMap<String, Pojo> result = new HashMap<String, Pojo>();
    log.debug("Load All Key count :" + Arrays.toString(keys.toArray()));
    for (String key : keys) {
        listPojo = load(key);
        if (listPojo != null && !listPojo.isEmpty()) {
            for (Pojo pojo: listPojo) {
                log.debug("Key :" + pojo.getId());
                result.put(pojo.getId(), pojo);
            }
        }
    }
//  log.debug("Load All Total Count :" + result.size());
    return result;
}
```

My question is how to implement this because as per mapstore we have to return same type object, that is List<Pojo> for load() method means we have to return    Map<String,List<Pojo>>

But for me I need to return Map<String, Pojo> for loadAll() method. Can someone please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Can you please specify exactly what is the key & value types of your `IMap`? Is it `IMap<String, List<Pojo>>` or `IMap<String, Pojo>` ?

Comment: This is for MapStore implementation. for load(String key) returns List<Pojo> and for loadAll(collection<String> keys) should return Map<String, List<Pojo>>, instead I would like to return Map<String, Pojo>

Comment: I understand this is for MapStore. What I'm trying to say is, MapStore's key&value types must be the same with `IMap` itself. Also if `loadAllKeys()` returns `Iterable<K> `, then `loadAll(Collection<K> keys)` should return `Map<K, V> `.

Comment: For our scenario for each "key" the DB2 stored proc will return 1000's of records, that is on key will have list<V>. Example: for a given "StoreID", i will have 1000's of products, once I get that list I need Iterate and create a unique ID as key with a single record to insert into that MAP.. If you have any email ID, please do share, so that I will explain my scenario better.